# Trying to prevent duplicate random item in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Can anyone help me with this? All I need to do is prevent a duplicate from showing. I am populating an array and randomly generating the recipes. When you refresh the page, sometimes the same item appears twice. I need to prevent this from happening. I included a Fiddle at the bottom thanks.

Below is my code:

```
 var recipe_data = [
   {
      "id":"11",
      "recipeName":"Hummus",
      "recipeCategory":"4",
      "recipeImageCategoryURL":"http://www.slurrpy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/roasted-eggplant-hummus-800x500.jpg"
   },
   {
      "id":"12",
      "recipeName":"Antipasto",
      "recipeCategory":"4",
      "recipeImageCategoryURL":"http://static.menutabapp.com/img/cache/800x500/2012/10/23/7857b394d50293d29443dc09eac76b3d.jpeg"
   },
   {
      "id":"10",
      "recipeName":"Zucchini",
      "recipeCategory":"4",
      "recipeImageCategoryURL":"https://paleofood.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/garlic-shrimp-zucchini-noodle-main-800x500.jpg"
   }
]

     var categoryItems = [];

         $.each(recipe_data, function(i, item){
            if (item.recipeCategory == "4") { categoryItems.push(item); }
         });

         var similarRecipe = '';
         var randomRecipe = {};


         for(var i = 0; i < categoryItems.length; i ++) {

            randomRecipe = categoryItems[Math.floor(Math.random()*categoryItems.length)];
            categoryItems.length = 2;

            similarRecipe = [ '<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 img-margin">' + ' <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox" data-url="' + randomRecipe.recipePageURL +'" data-title="' + randomRecipe.recipeName + '"></div>' 
            + '<a href="' + randomRecipe.recipePageURL +'">' + '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + randomRecipe.recipeImageCategoryURL + '">' + '</a>' 
            + '<a href="' + randomRecipe.recipePageURL +'">' + '<h3 class="recipeSubCategoryImgCaption">' + randomRecipe.recipeName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>' ]; 
            $('#recipeSimilar').append(similarRecipe);  

        }
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wn4fmm5r/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After picking a random item, just remove it from the array so it's not picked again:

```
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*categoryItems.length);

randomRecipe = categoryItems[randomIndex];

categoryItems.splice(randomIndex, 1);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bLpqvs4f

Answer (score 1):

I suppose in this case you want to take `n` different items from `recipe_data`?
In this case you should write a specified function to get the items you want

```
function getRandomItems(noOfItems, source){
    var samples = source.slice();
    var results = [];

    for(var i=0; i < noOfItems;i++){
        results = results.concat(samples.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * samples.length), 1));
    }

    return results;
}
```

Some things to note here is to use `.slice()` to shallow copy an array, instead of running a for loop to add items, and when you want to pull items from an array `.splice()` is the function to choose.

See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wn4fmm5r/3/

Answer (score 1):

May store the last recipe id in local storage, to prevent of showing it again (i suppose refreshing means reloading the page?)?

```
var showed=localStorage.getItem("stored")||[];//get the recipes already showed
var id;
while(!id||showed.find(el=>el===id)){//retry until generated a new one
     id=Math.floor(Math.random()*categoryItems.length);//generate new one
}
showed.push(id);
localStorage.setItem("stored",showed);//store again
randomRecipe = categoryItems[id];//your new & random recipe
```

Unlike the other answers, this also work with browser refreshes...